# How can i make menu like the picture below in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu, icons

How to create a pinned shortcut [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XHGG.jpg) so when the user long clicks on the app launcher logo create a shortcut that navigates to a certain activity like:
1:Record voice note
2:Type note
3:......

Preferably using java.

Comment: There are three types of shortcuts you can read about them here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Those are [App shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts). The official android developer documentation shows [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts) how to create static and dynamic shortcuts.

Static shortcuts don't change during a version of your app.As stated in the documentation, a good example would be a shortcut to the "sent messages" in a messaging app.

Dynamic shortcuts can change. In a messanging app this could be for example a shortcut to "send message to last contact".

Comment: tnx its was very helpful i dont know that the name of those are App shourtcuts.